# Send reminder email one day before task due date

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a calculated variable called SendEmailDate (*=[Due Date]-1*), which will be used to determnie when to send the reminder email because I want something to go out one day before the task is due.

Here is what I currently have for my workflow.

```
-- First step
If Status == Completed
    Stop task

-- Second step
If SendEmailDate == Today (how do I get this?)
    Send reminder email
Else
    Pause until SendEmailDate
```

I'm pretty sure that the logic above will work. But how do I get the current date in a workflow? I did find [this](http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/the-dog-ate-my-task-use-sharepoint-designer-to-email-daily-task-reminders) which shows how to loop a workflow but that didn't really help me in my cause.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the formula list in Sharepoint Designer, isn't there an option for "Current Date" that you can drop into your workflow?

Comment: Thank you very much. :)

I was overlooking the '...' button.